# Does the default email app support IMAP?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, email, imap

Does the default email app in Android 2.2 support IMAP rather than just POP?

Answer (score 4):

Default email app on my G2 supports IMAP, including encryption. I personally use K-9, which is free.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use GMail? Or the default "E-Mail App"? Which device you own (Samsung has another than stock google). 
But I remember, that both of them support IMAP.